# How to create a spark dataframe with timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I create this spark dataframe with timestamp data type in one step?  Here is how I am doing it in two steps.  Using spark 2.4

First create dataframe with timestamp strings

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp

val eventData = Seq(
  Row(1, "2014/01/01 23:00:01"), 
  Row(1, "2014/11/30 12:40:32"), 
  Row(2, "2016/12/29 09:54:00"), 
  Row(2, "2016/05/09 10:12:43")
)

val schema = StructType(List(
  StructField("typeId", IntegerType, false),
  StructField("eventTimeString", StringType, false)
))

val eventDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  sc.parallelize(eventData),
  schema
)
eventDF.show()

+------+-------------------+
|typeId|    eventTimeString|
+------+-------------------+
|     1|2014/01/01 23:00:01|
|     1|2014/11/30 12:40:32|
|     2|2016/12/29 09:54:00|
|     2|2016/05/09 10:12:43|
+------+-------------------+
```

Then convert string to timestamp and drop string column

```
 val eventTimestampsDF = eventDF
  .withColumn("eventTime", to_timestamp($"eventTimeString", "yyyy/MM/dd k:mm:ss"))
  .drop($"eventTimeString")
```

How can I eliminate the second step and create timestamps directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can to this like this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-01-01 23:00:01")),
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-11-30 12:40:32")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-12-29 09:54:00")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-09 10:12:43"))
).toDF("typeId","eventTime")
```

No need to use `Row` objects and custom schema

Comment: I had tried to use java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf() like this but it didn't recognize my format and doesn't take format as a parameter and so was returning null for some timestamps.  Somehow spark.implicits._ magically makes everything good.  I need to learn more about this magic import.